# Bit-reversal algorithm by Rutkowska

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, fft, permutation

I found a very interesting paper about bit-reversal algorithm suitable for in-place FFT: "A simple algorithm for the bit-reversal permutation" by 
Urszula Rutkowska from 1990 (doi.org/10.1016/0165-1684(91)90008-7).

However, her algorithm G1 does not appear to work as the very first iteration results in out-of-bounds error for that `N1 = L << 1` and `swap(a + 1, a + N1);`. I assume `L` means the length of input vector.

Please, does anyone know if there was any errata for the paper or how to fix the algorithm?

The paper's pseudocode:

```
G1(L)
{int     i,j,L1
         N1,N2,a,b;
unsigned k;
j=0;    L1=L-1;
N1=L<<1;N2=N1+1;
for(i=0;i<L1;i++)
{if(i<j)
    { a=i<<1;
      b=j<<1;
      swap(a,b);
      swap(a+N2,b+N2);
      swap(a+1,b+N1);
      swap(b+1,a+N1);
    }
 else
    if(i==j)
    { a=i<<1;
      swap(a+1,a+N1);
    }
 k=L>>1;
 while(k<=j){ j=j-k;
              k=k>>1;
            }
 j+=k;
 }
 i<<=1;
 swap(i+1,i+N1);
}
```

Screenshot of the paper:

[image]

Comment: Let me suggest using Elster's linear-time algorithm: https://www.idi.ntnu.no/~elster/pubs/elster-bit-rev-1989.pdf (see Algorithm 3; `n = 2^t`). [Disclaimer: Elster was my advisor.]

Comment: This was migrated from DSP, but I don't see how this fits better here than there. It would be nice if the moderator @jojek who migrated this could explain why. For one, images of code is a big no-no here.

Comment: I posted a question regarding this migration on Meta DSP: https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1602/why-was-this-question-migrated-to-so

Comment: Probably the shift operator is in the wrong dimension. It makes no much sense to do something with twice of the array size. Instead it is much more likely that the array is split into two slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was pretty garbled, frankly. I had to read the paper for the idea (run Gold's algorithm (G) for L/4 and then derive the swaps for L) and then sort of massage the code into the right form. Here's my final result.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static bool is_power_of_two(int L) { return L > 0 && (L & (L - 1)) == 0; }

static void swap(int i, int j) { printf("swap %d,%d\n", i, j); }

static void G(int L) {
  assert(is_power_of_two(L));
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < L - 1; i++) {
    if (i < j) {
      swap(i, j);
    }
    int k = L >> 1;
    while (j >= k) {
      j -= k;
      k >>= 1;
    }
    j += k;
  }
}

static void G1(int L) {
  assert(is_power_of_two(L));
  if (L < 4) {
    return;
  }
  int j = 0;
  int N1 = L >> 1;
  int N2 = N1 + 1;
  int L2 = L >> 2;
  for (int i = 0; i < L2 - 1; i++) {
    if (i < j) {
      int a = i << 1;
      int b = j << 1;
      swap(a, b);
      swap(a + N2, b + N2);
      swap(a + 1, b + N1);
      swap(b + 1, a + N1);
    } else if (i == j) {
      int a = i << 1;
      swap(a + 1, a + N1);
    }
    int k = L2 >> 1;
    while (j >= k) {
      j -= k;
      k >>= 1;
    }
    j += k;
  }
  int a = (L2 - 1) << 1;
  swap(a + 1, a + N1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  assert(1 < argc);
  int L = atoi(argv[1]);
  G(L);
  putchar('\n');
  G1(L);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm it works now! PS: Karp benchmarks several bit-reversal algorithms in his [Bit Reversal on Uniprocessors](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/93/HPL-93-89.pdf) paper, it would be interesting to know how exactly he fixed it.

Comment: The official citation for my bit reversal paper is "Bit Reversals on Uniprocessors", SIAM Review, vol. 38, #1, 1--26, March (1996). (I tried to put this citation in a comment, but the system wouldn't let me.)

Comment: In a private communication Alan Karp was kind enough to let me see his implementation and the only difference was the second last line here reads `a = (L2 - 1) << 1`, whereas in his code it was akin to `a = i << 1`. Which, of course, results in the same output.

Comment: @minmax Yeah, I wanted the loop variable scoped to the loop, even at the cost of a redundant arithmetic op.